# Proper parameter-passing of inline onclick string with multiple passes

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, escaping, parameter-passing

I have two different side-panels with different settings, but would like to use one "login" form to access either depending on whether I clicked link A or B.  So, I need to use the original string from either links' onclick attribute to change the onclick attribute of the "login" form so I can then pass that string into the function it uses.

I am admit-tingly a newb, albeit a quick learner. I am missing something here and can't figure it out, and may even be going in the wrong direction, so if I am please straighten me out! :)

Link A 
`<a href="#" id="leftOpen" onclick="openLogin(leftPanel)"></a>`

Link B 
`<a href="#" id="rightOpen" onclick="openLogin(rightPanel)"></a>`

Login Link 
`<a href="#" id="loginBtn" onclick="openPanel()"></a>`

Login Link should be this after first function if clicked Link A
`<a href="#" id="loginBtn" onclick="openPanel(leftPanel)"></a>`

Functions

```
function openLogin(panel){
    var panel;
    $("#login").css("z-index", "1000");
    $("#login").addClass("show");
    document.getElementByID("#loginBtn").setAttribute("onclick","openPanel(\" . panel . \")");
    };

function openPanel(open){
    var open;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            result=xmlhttp.responseText;
                if (result == 0) {
                    $("#login").css("z-index", "-1");
                    $("#login").removeClass("show");
                    $("#" . open).addClass("openSettings");  // Got to be something wrong here!
                    document.getElementById("pwd").value='';
                }
                else {
                    alert("The password entered is incorrect.")
                    document.getElementById("pwd").value='';
                }
        }
    }
    var url="../somewhere/mychk.php?pwd="+document.getElementById("pwd").value;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
};
```

Comment: the concatenation operator in javascript is `+`, not `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in a string in your `onclick` events, for the `id` of your panels

```
<a href="#" id="leftOpen" onclick="openLogin('leftPanel')"></a>
```

You are redefining `panel` in `openLogin`, thus overwriting whatever you pass in

```
function openLogin(panel){

    // remove this line
    // var panel;

    $("#login").css("z-index", "1000");
    $("#login").addClass("show");
    document.getElementByID("#loginBtn").setAttribute("onclick", "openPanel('" + panel + "')");
};
```

Depending on what your panel(s) `id`s are, if you use the correct concatenation operator, the following should work

```
$("#" + open).addClass("openSettings");
```

Comment: Kavun, I'm about to try this out, but I am unsure what you mean with the "correct concatenation operator". Would you mind elaborating on this please?